# Windows 7 and Linux fedora do not recognize my Samsung 850 evo SSD, but the BIOS does

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, ssd, bios

A few days ago I got a blue screen in windows, and my system restarted. After that, when I try to turn on my computer, the ASUS logo stays up for a long time (like 2-3 minutes) and then goes into a black screen with a cursor on the top left side for half a minute to a minute, and then goes into the BIOS setup.

I tried swapping around RAM modules, unplugging everything and then plugging components in one by one and narrowed the problem down to the SSD.

The BIOS does recognize the SSD, but can't boot into it. I tried SATA Mode Selection to AHCI or IDE but nothing changes, except for the wait time I think.

Here are my specs:

Motherboard H97-PLUS
Bios Ver. 2504
CPU Intel Core i5-4590 3.3GHz
memory 16384 MB DDR3 1600 MHz

I tried different cables, different ports, but nothing works. I tried plugging the SSD through USB to a different windows 10 computer, it did not recognize it. Tried same with a Linux Fedora computer, nothing there either. I tried to plug the SSD to my fedora laptop through SATA, but that caused the laptop to fail to boot properly, it took way too long and instead of going to the desktop, it went to a CLI instead after the fedora logo. (I am a linux noob btw, still learning.) The laptop uses an M.2 SSD as main boot drive.

I tried booting into a win7 installation disk and used diskpart, but list disk says that There are no fixed disks to show.
If I try to install windows 7, it won't list any drives. When I tried a Fedora installation stick, it gave an error, failure to read sectors I believe it was. I can re-confirm if need be, it failed to read 3 sectors that it listed, two times each, and then offered me a live boot. I went with it and tried to install but it did not show any drives.

I've had this drive for over a year I believe (no warranty btw...) I am not sure what else to try, the only hope I have left is the fact that my BIOS recognizes it.

Is it possible to save the drives content? Or at least fix it so that I can use it still? Or are both options impossible?

At this point I am assuming the drive is 100% dead but giving it a last shot.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:
I tried to connect the SSD to my fedora laptop through USB, and tried GParted but it did not list the drive. I know the USB adapter works with 2.5" HDDs... but now I am not entirely sure if it's not working with the SSD, or just the SSD is not responding. Guessing it's the latter.

EDIT 2:
I tried a new adapter, and also tested it on a different SSD, confirmed to be working, but it won't work with the broken SSD. Gparted doesn't see it either.

Comment: Can Gparted see the drive?

Comment: I just tried that, it does not list it. However now I am not 100% sure if the adapter I am using is working with the SSD. It does work with a 2.5" HDD though. Going to add that

Comment: Can you test the adapter with a known good drive? or this drive with a different adapter to narrow it down? Not looking good for your drive unfortunately if Gparted can't see it..

Comment: I do not have another SSD or adapter. The adapter does work with a 2.5" HDD though. Also yeah, once I was unable to see my drive in linux I pretty much lost hope. The only thing I have in mind now is plugging the SSD to my laptops sata slot and boot into fedora (M.2 SSD boot drive), and maybe there is something I could do at the CLI after fedora fails to get into the desktop? Not familiar with the commands though...

Comment: Unfortunately not looking very likely to get anything from the drive